# PopupWindow BadTokenException Edittext requestFocus

Tags: android, android-fragments, popupwindow

I have a PopopWindow where the user can register and account.
If the username already exist, i use setError(string); to notify the user and
then i clear the Edittext and reqeustFocus. But on reqeustFocus(); i get BadTokenException:

```
Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41ea39b8 is not valid; is your activity running
```

I'm using SherlockFragment and this is how i create the PopupWindow

```
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_register,null);
     pwCreateAccount = new PopupWindow(layout, screenWidth - 75, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
     pwCreateAccount.setOutsideTouchable(true);
     pwCreateAccount.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
     pwCreateAccount.showAtLocation(layout, 17, 0, 0);
```

I had the same problem with a spinner inside the PopupWindow, then i tried to open the dropdown to select an item i got same error. But i also used getActivity() and not getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Dialog

```
         myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
     myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_register);
     myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

This way i get my own view, no border from the default background or title